# Field Calculator error when calculating length and widths of polygon in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator

I'm using this formula to calculate the length of some polygons:

```
[Perimeter]/4 +(Sqr ( ([Perimeter]/2)^2-4* [Area] )/2)
```

There are over 50,000 entries and it has only managed to calculate a handful. However, when I click on the uncalculated entries individually or in groups of two and use the above formula, it is able to come up with the results.

It's coming with Error: 999999: Error executing function ; Invalid procedure call or argument: "Sqr".

I've checked the fields for negative values and run the repair geometry tool- both did not work.

I'm using ArcMap

How do I fix this?

Comment: The error doesn't occur when "calculating length and widths", it comes in the `Sqr` function, as stated by the error.  In what format is the data?  What parser are you using to process the rows?  Is there a `Sqr` function?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Arc. I used the calculate geometry tool to get the values in the perimeter and area fields. They are both in double format

Comment: Calculate Geometry Attributes is not "Field Calculator"; "double" is a column type, not a data format -- data formats include shapefile, file geodatabase, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server,... Please [Edit] the Question to describe the exact software, the exact command, and the exact inputs into the function. You should also describe why you thought this would be valid syntax, since it certainly doesn't look like a Calculate Geometry Attributes input. If you go into the geoprocessing results log, you can "Copy as Python snippet" and paste that in the Question.